# sphinx / reStructuredText - math mode inside block quote

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Im attempting to quote a source in my docs and that source includes math symbols.  Is it possible to use the latex math symbols inside of a block quote?  I've tried the following in my python docstring with no luck.

```
.. pull-quote::

            `"As density perturbations behave differently in a radiation
            dominated universe versus a matter dominated one due to pressure
            support, the scale of the particle horizon at the equality epoch
            :math:`z_{\rm eq}` "`

.. math::

            k_{\rm eq} = (2 \Omega_{\rm M} H_0^2 z_{\rm eq})^{1/2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out you CAN do this in a block quote but not inside a block of italics (the backticks).  If you end the italics block, put the math in, then restart the italics block, things work out fine. Updated example below,

```
.. pull-quote::

            `"As density perturbations behave differently in a 
            radiation dominated universe versus a matter dominated one
            due to pressure support, the scale of the particle horizon
            at the equality epoch` :math:`z_{\rm eq}` `more quote text
            can go here"`

.. math::

            k_{\rm eq} = (2 \Omega_{\rm M} H_0^2 z_{\rm eq})^{1/2}
```